# Upper and Lower Eigenvalue Bounds for $X^{T} A X$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times n}$ be diagonal with $i$th diagonal element $a_{ii}$ (i.e. all $a_{ii} > 0$), and let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ be a matrix with rank $p$ where $n \ge p$ (in particular, consider a design matrix for regression).

Consider the matrix $X^{T} A X$. I'm interested in finding upper bounds on the matrix's largest eigenvalue, and lower bounds on the matrix's smallest eigenvalue. Alternatively, if $v \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, I would be interested in upper and lower bounds for $v^{T} X^{T} A X v$. Ideally these bounds would relate to the matrix $X^{T} X$, or $\lambda_{max}(X^{T} X)$ and $\lambda_{min}(X^{T}X)$. It's clear that

$$ v^{T} X^{T} A X v \le \underset{i = 1, \ldots, p}{max} [a_{ii}] \cdot v^{T} X^{T} X v \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii} \right) \cdot v^{T} X^{T} X v \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii} \right) \cdot \lambda_{max}(X^{T} X) \cdot v^{T} v. $$

It's also relatively clear that

$$ v^{T} X^{T} A X v \ge \underset{i = 1, \ldots, p}{min} [a_{ii}] \cdot v^{T} X^{T} X v \ge \underset{i = 1, \ldots, p}{min} [a_{ii}] \cdot \lambda_{min}(X^{T} X) \cdot v^T v.$$

It would be ideal for me to have some type of lower bound on $v^{T} X^{T} A X v$ that relates to the trace of $A$. Does anyone have any ideas for how to achieve such a bound? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: the 1st inequality is better written as $\Big\Vert X^TAX\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}\leq \Big\Vert X^T\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}\Big\Vert A\Big \Vert_{S_\infty} \Big \Vert X\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}=  \Big\Vert A \Big\Vert_{S_\infty} \Big\Vert X^TX\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}\leq \Big\Vert A \Big\Vert_{S_1} \Big\Vert X^TX\Big\Vert_{S_\infty}$.  Where $S$ denotes Schatten norm ($\infty$ norm is operator 2 norm and schatten 1 norm is nuclear norm).  These norms are submultiplicative; triangle inequality should make you suspicious of using the trace for a lower bound. (Also consider rank $n-1$ A by continuity)

Comment: @user8675309 I'm definitely having issues using the trace for a lower bound. What I'm really after is a bound on $v^{T} (X^{T} A X + M)^{-1} v$, where $M$ is positive definite. I need the bound to have $\mbox{tr}(A)$ in the denominator, and would ideally have an eigenvalue of $X^{T} X$ in the denominator as well.